# How to put keys of a dictionary as a column value in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I've two dataframes `df & df1` and i've converted the `df1` to a dictionary as it contains only two columns. As shown below:

```
import pandas as pandas
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
df['company'] = 0
df1 = pd.read_csv('data1.csv')

mydict = dict(zip(df1.agent_id, df1.company))

for x in df.agent_id:
   for k,v in mydict.items():
      if k == x:
        df.loc[df['company']] = v
```

Now i want to append the value of `mydict` as a value in column `df['company']` if it fulfils the following conditions. How can i do this? can somebody explain? I know i'm just missing a simple logic. I can't figure it out though.

if`df` is this

```
        agent_id
0            184
1            182
2            113
3            157
4            137
5            199
6            181
```

and `mydict` is this:

```
mydict = {184: 'LuxuryPods',
          113: 'smartflat.com',
          157: 'ApartaMinutes',
          199: 'HouseMouse',
          181: 'LuxuryPods',
          182: 'Ramax',
          137: 'LuxuryPods'}
```

then the resultant `df` should look like this:

```
        agent_id      company
0            184      LuxuryPods
1            182      Ramax
2            113      smartflat.com
3            157      ApartaMinutes
4            137      LuxuryPods
5            199      HouseMouse
6            181      LuxuryPods
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try the following code

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'agent_id': [184, 182, 113, 157]})

mydict = {184: 'LuxuryPods',
          113: 'smartflat.com',
          157: 'ApartaMinutes',
          182: 'Ramax'}

df['company'] = df['agent_id'].map(mydict)
```

Output

```
   agent_id        company
0       184     LuxuryPods
1       182          Ramax
2       113  smartflat.com
3       157  ApartaMinutes
```

The key is basically to use the `map` function to map all values in `agent_id` to their corresponding company. With the `map` function, you can also specify what values you want, in the case where there's no match found. The argument is `na_action`.